# How to keep aspect ratio for images added in jspdf

Tags: image, jspdf, aspect-ratio

I want to generate pdf's with jspdf. These pdf's are a summary of an registration that users make in my app with an picture and some notes.

However when generating a pdf I need to supply the height and width of the image. first of I don't know this (though I can figure it out) second if the dimensions are bigger then my pdf they won't fit. And if i just make them smaller the aspect ratio will be ruined.

I am kinda looking for a solution much like in html where you use things like 'width: 70vw; height: auto;'

Any idea's on how to fix this?